# Load 404 state with AngularJS Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) and [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and have the following code which catches 404's and loads in a 404 template:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
  $injector.invoke(['$state', function($state) {
    $state.go('404');
  }]);
});
```

It keeps the URL intact instead of redirecting, but shows the 404 template:

```
.state('404',
{
    views: {
        'body': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/404.html',
        }
    }
});
```

Normally it would redirect to the root state with: `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');`

However when HTML5 mode is turned off and the user visits the root URL e.g. `http://www.domain.com/app/` it loads the 404 state instead of redirecting to `http://www.domain.com/app/#/`

How can I keep the 404 state code above, but have it redirect to the hashbang when accessing the initial page? So effectively only have the 404 load if the request is anything other than the home page?

I can't use the `$stateNotFound` or `$stateChangeSuccess` and need a way to check if it's a home page request within the actual config setup itself that can toggle between the `/` and the `state.404` within the otherwise statement.

Comment: can you provide more code details

Comment: Do you want a solution for both HTML5 mode on and off? If you ship your application in only one mode, it would be easier to discuss possible solutions. I know one solution at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So something along the lines of (which does seem to work).

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
    $injector.invoke(['$state', function($state) {
        if( $location.$$path == '')
            $state.go('home'); // redirect to /#/
        else
            $state.go('404'); // else go to 404 state
    }]);
});
```

But is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `httpErrorResponseInterceptor`! This will get fired when a httpResponse happens.  Here is an example

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .factory('httpErrorResponseInterceptor', ['$q', '$state', function ($q, $state) {
     return {
         responseError: function error(response) {
             switch (response.status) {
                 case 404:
                     $state.go('404');
                     break;

                 default:
                     console.log("Unhandled HTTP error:", response);
             }

             return $q.reject(response);
         }
     };
 }
]);
```